# Yii2 auto complete - value missing in the field on update

Tags: php, yii2

I am using the yii2 auto complete widget, it is working fine, except when I update the form the field shows blank.

```
use yii\jui\AutoComplete;
use yii\web\JsExpression;

$data = app\models\Doctor::find()
    ->select(['doctor_name as value', 'doctor_name as  label','id as id'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

and after that the auto-complete code like this

```
echo 'Doctor' .'<br>';
  echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'Doctor',    
    'id' => 'ddd',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => $data, 
        'autoFill'=>true,
         'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
        $('#appoinment-doctor_name').val(ui.item.id);
     }")],
     ]);
<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'doctor_name')?>
```

What I am missing here? How can I get the value on update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly set [`value`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-inputwidget.html#$value-detail):

```
echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'Doctor',    
    'id' => 'ddd',
    'value' => $model->doctor_name,
    ...
```

This isn't necessary if you set `model` and `attribute` though.

Comment: Topher - Thanks It works fine, but I have to modify it like - `'value' => (!$model->isNewRecord ? $model->doctorName->doctor_name:''),` . Thanks once again.